# SOAP client with node.js and socket.io

Tags: php, node.js, soap, asynchronous, socket.io

I am trying to create a web app using Node.js. I want to use socket.io to stream data that I pull from a soap service. I am having trouble finding any information about this. what would be the best option for this situation.

right now:

- I am using PHP to call a soap service and retrieve data.
- my client side java script makes interval calls using AJAX to the PHP function containing the SOAP call.(this is inefficient which is why I would like to switch to socket.io setup).

What I would like to do:

- Node.js app with express possibly
- SOAP call using PHP or Node.js if possible.
- stream data from SOAP to client side to be viewed using socket.io

I am not sure if this setup is possible and I have not found and good documentation on this. would this be possible ? if so, what would be the best method or is there a tutorial for this?

Comment: why do you need a soap client ? if you are planning to use socket io and node js

Comment: I am connecting to a 3rd party's soap server to get data. I will throw out SOAP if socket.io can get this info from the wsdl?

Answer (score 1):

There is excellent node.js module called 'soap', you may get it via `npm install soap`. Also see the docs at https://github.com/milewise/node-soap.

Comment: however this soap module creates a new socket for each call to server over a https connection even when connection-keepalive is set. It works fine in http mode maintaining a single socket for multiple calls when keep alive is set.